# Slick "===" compiling only in for comprehension

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I am experiencing a strange behaviour with slick and I would like some help figuring out why it happens. The issue is that I have a query that reads as follows:

```
db.withSession { implicit session =>
  tables.users.where(_.id === UserId(1)).firstOption
}
```

This does not compile producing an error as follows:

```
inferred type arguments [Boolean] do not conform to method where's type parameter bounds [T <: scala.slick.lifted.Column[_]]
```

But if I rewrite the code as:

```
db.withSession { implicit session =>
  (for {
    u <- tables.users if u.id === UserId(1)
  } yield u).firstOption
}
```

It compiles and works fine.

The table is defined as follows:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[UserId]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.NotNull)
}
```

And I have an implicit conversion to map the UserId type:

```
implicit lazy val userIdColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[UserId, Int](_.value, UserId(_))
```

It looks like a type inference problem, but I can't really understand why it should happen.

Anyone has any on why this should behave differently in the two scenario I reported?

EDIT: After some investigation I found that when using `where` the implicit conversion for the `userIdColumnType` has to be in scope, while with the for comprehension it is not needed. Is there a good explanation for this?

Comment: Do you import === from some other library?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, it's being added by ScalaTest as that code is part of some tests that I'm writing; is that the issue? If yes, how come it is correctly behaving if I put the `userIdColumnType` in scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using === from ScalaTest. It returns a Boolean. Slick's === returns a `Column[Boolean]`. The methods `filter` and `where` prevent using Boolean (at least in the latest version of Slick), to protect you from accidentally using `==` or also from using ScalaTest's `===` in your case, which does a local comparison of the underlying values instead of an equality comparison in the database, which is what you actualy want. For comprehensions are desugared to `withFilter` and can sometimes generate a Boolean value, so unfortunately we cannot disallow `Boolean` for comprehensions.

To fix this you need to make sure, that Slick's `===` is picked in queries. Maybe you can affect this with the import order or scope. Or if you are unlucky you can't and they are incompatible.

I am not sure how the userIdColumnType interacts here at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by importing my driver api and making sure it was in scope

i.e. as I'm using a postgresql driver, 
`import PostgresProfile.api._`